# How to get the second slug of a page url?

Tags: php, html

I have posts with a `custom field` called `year`. The year ranges from `1900 to 2011`. I want to create an individual page for each year which will displays the posts with that year. So I will be creating a page with a template and a custom query to find all posts with that specific year.

However, instead of creating 100+ individual year pages I want to just create 1 page which will extract the parameter from the URL and into a variable and then find the posts with that variable.

So instead of creating individual pages like `base.com/year/1990 , base.com/year/1991, base.com/year/1992` I just want to create one page and extract the year.
So for example I want to extract `2008` out of this page URL:

```
http://www.base.com/year/2008
```

I already know I can extract `year` by using this code:

```
$post->post_name;
```

but how to I get additional parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved with the [WordPress Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)

### The simplest way

I assume that you've created a page called `year` and the request is most probably matched to this rule `(.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$`, with the query rewritten to `pagename=year`.

However, you will notice from the regular expression that an additional `/` can be matched to with numbers following it.

Requesting `/year/1999` will transform the query to `pagename=year&page=%2F1999`. Thus `page` is what will contain `1999`. And you can get to it using `get_query_var('page');` and feed it to your custom query by using use the simple [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and feed it the extra `meta_key` and `meta_value` to retrieve your posts like so:

```
$args['meta_key'] = 'year';
$args['meta_value'] = get_query_var('page');
// ... other arguments
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

### But isn't this wrong?

If using this unexpected result and behavior of taking page and feeding it in as year this feels wrong, you can go about achieving the same result in a different way by [adding your own rewrite rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

By adding a rule that will match `^year/([^/]\d+)/?'` and rewrite to `pagename=year&custom_year=$matches[1]` you will be able to access `custom_year` via `$wp` global object.

```
// this has to be done only once!
add_rewrite_rule('^year/([^/]\d+)/?',
    'index.php?pagename=year&custom_year=$matches[1],
    'top');
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

The code above should be wrapped to be hooked into the `init` action. The query itself can be accessed retrieved from the `$wp->matched_query` property and has to be parsed:

```
global $wp; // may be required to bring into scope

$q_args = array();
parse_str($wp->matched_query, $q_args);
$custom_year = $q_args['custom_year'];

$args['meta_key'] = 'year';
$args['meta_value'] = get_query_var('custom_year');
// ... other arguments
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

Note how you pick the name of your custom query field and make sure it's not in danger of collision with any of the [reserved terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms).

### Another way of looking at it

You may be better off looking at the whole situation from an archive's perspective rather than a page. If you register your own custom taxonomy for your posts instead of a custom field, you'll be able to query for posts based on that taxonomy without the manually adding additional rewrite rules.

The [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function will allow you to add your `custom_year` taxonomy and query for it getting archive pages back, without additional parsing, queries, etc.

You may have to `flush_rewrite_rules()` once after registering the taxonomies in order to flush some new rules WordPress automatically generates when registering taxonomies.

Take note of the `rewrite` argument you supply to `register_taxonomy()`, set it to `custom_year` and you should be able to query for posts in the taxonomy without further modifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $post;
// This is how you get the year of a post, not from the URL
$post_year = idate('Y', strtotime("{$post->post_created_gmt} GMT"));
```

And to get them from the DB you do this:

```
global $wpdb;
$archive = array();
foreach(($rows = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT `ID`, YEAR(`post_date_gmt`) AS `Year` FROM {$wpdb->posts}
        WHERE `post_type`='post' ORDER BY `post_date_gmt` DESC;"
)) as $row){
    if(!isset($archive[$row->Year])){
        $archive[$row->Year] = array();
    }
    $archive[$row->Year][] = $row->ID;
}
foreach($archive as $year => $posts){
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $permalink = get_permalink($post);
        $post = get_post($post);
        // Do stuff with $year and $post here
    }
}
```

Now you can add you own code instead of **// Do stuff with $year...** and do what you wish with the posts. If you have tens of thousands of posts, you need to optimize this a bit by grouping by year.

It's a starting point.

*Regards.*

Comment: Thanks, sorry if you missed it but I think I said that year is a custom field. I'm not trying to get the year the post was published but the year I added to a custom field. I'm advertising some books and some of them were released between 1900 - 2011.

Comment: @Jonny What's the name of the field that holds the YEAR? I'll rewrite the queries for that exact custom field value.

Answer (score 0):

**REMIX**:

```
global $wpdb;
$archive = array();
foreach(($rows = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT t1.`ID`, t2.`meta_value` AS `Year` FROM
        {$wpdb->posts} AS t1, {$wpdb->postmeta} AS t2
    WHERE t2.`meta_key`='year' AND
        t1.`ID` = t2.`post_id` AND
        t1.`post_type`='post'
    ORDER BY `Year` DESC, `post_date_gmt` DESC;"
)) as $row){
    if(!isset($archive[$row->Year])){
        $archive[$row->Year] = array();
    }
    $archive[$row->Year][] = $row->ID;
}
foreach($archive as $year => $posts){
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $permalink = get_permalink($post);
        $post = get_post($post);
        // Do stuff with $year and $post here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps as a foundation :)

*Regards.*